# Lists Merge and reduce without using inbuilt functions

Tags: scala, recursion

Consider an example

```
val a= List(1,2,3)
val b= List(4,5,6)
```

merge reduce function taking two lists and two function where one function acts as merge and another function to reduce it to Integer more of a general form.

merge by multiplying the head of two lists and then reduce using add
merge using max then get the min of the generated list

```
mergeReduce(a,b,product,add) = 32

mergeReduce(a,b,max,min) = 4
```

This can be achieved using inbuilt functions but is there a better way to do without the use of those functions in a recursive manner.

Comment: both the list will have the same number of element always?

Comment: For the given example Lists, How the second mergeReduce result becomes 4. Can you please explain?

Comment: @Raman Mishra, I think It must be same. If not, how the product yeilds a List of products of corresponding elements?

Comment: The first mergeReduce function  is understandable, But I couldn't figure out how the second one gives a result of 4.

Comment: `mergeReduce(a,b,product,min) = 4, and mergeReduce(a,b,product,max) = 18,` as per my understanding..@.Venkat can you please respond on this?

Comment: Merge function is max so it is max(1,4)=4 it continues for rest of the tail of a and b like (2,5)=5 and (3,6) =6 a new list is generated like (4,5,6) and a min is used to reduce on the list so the answer is 4. Same logic goes for prod and sum

Comment: it should be 
mergeReduce(a,b,product,add) = 32 ,
mergeReduce(a,b,max,min) = 4

Comment: so you first want to apply product then sum, and in 2nd case you want first max then min of that list?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems did you come across?

Comment: so you first want to apply product then sum, and in 2nd case you want first max then min of that list? – Yes And it be should be generic where i can pass the functions to mergeReduce function

Comment: I did create a function for prod and sum like consider lists l1 and l2

(l1.head*l2.head)+mergeReduce(l1.tail,l2.tail)

But not able to create a generic type where it can do min and max also

Comment: What are the return types of the functions` product, add, min and max`?

Comment: What are the return types of the functions` product, add, min and max`? - Int

Comment: Is it OK to  return a tuple containing` (product,add)` and `(min,max)` form mergeReduce function?

Comment: No. The output of the mergereduce function is Int not tuple.

Comment: But i'm intrested in like how u can do that

Comment: @Venkat, As per your comments above, the return type of the first function, is understood to be a List of `Int`s  on which the second function will act on and return an Int result..Is it Right?

Answer (score 1):

Here is your `mergeReduce()` (as I understand it).

```
def mergeReduce(a :List[Int], b :List[Int]
               ,f :(Int,Int)=>Int, g :(Int,Int)=>Int) :Int =
  a.zip(b).map(f.tupled).reduce(g)

val a= List(1,2,3)
val b= List(4,5,6)
mergeReduce(a,b,_*_,_+_)           // 32
mergeReduce(a,b,math.max,math.min) // 4
```

So, what are the "inbuilt" functions you want to replace? And why do you want to replace them?

---

Here then is a version without `map`, `reduce`, `zip`, and `tupled`.

```
def mergeReduce(lsta :List[Int], lstb :List[Int]
               ,f :(Int,Int)=>Int, g :(Int,Int)=>Int) :Int = {

  def merg(x :List[Int], y :List[Int], acc :List[Int] = Nil) :List[Int] =
    if (x.isEmpty || y.isEmpty) acc.reverse
    else merg(x.tail, y.tail, f(x.head,y.head) :: acc)

  def reduc(z: List[Int]) :Int = z match {
    case Nil => -1 //error
    case i :: Nil => i
    case a::b::c => reduc(g(a,b) :: c)
  }

  reduc(merg(lsta, lstb))
}
```

This uses `.isEmpty`, `.reverse`, `.head`, `.tail`, and `.unapply` (the method by which pattern matching is accomplished). Still too much "inbuilt"?

Comment: Map, reduce, zip and tuple. To learn more about recursive programming without using any inbuilt functions

Comment: That's a much simpler question than the one you posted. If you had asked that directly then there wouldn't have been so much confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. It performs merge and reduce in a single pass, using only the basic `List` operations:

```
def mergeReduce[T](a: List[T], b: List[T], merge: (T, T) => T, reduce: (T, T) => T): T = {
  @tailrec
  def loop(a: List[T], b: List[T], res: T): T =
    (a, b) match {
      case (a :: at, b :: bt) => loop(at, bt, reduce(res, merge(a, b)))
      case _ => res
    }

  loop(a.tail, b.tail, merge(a.head, b.head))
}
```

This will fail if either list is `Nil` and will silently discard the values from the longer list if the lengths are not the same.